# Multiple buttons on one image using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a program that will perform different functions depending on which part of an image I click on. I'd be ok with cutting up the image into different parts and placing them together, but they are in the shape of a circle, so I'm not sure how well I'd even be able to cut it since i'm just using Paint, nor how accurately I could place those images back together.
I'll include the image I'm using below.

Is there a way to make a single image have multiple  buttons associated with it using python? I've mostly been looking at tkinter and could not figure out a way to do it.
If not, is there a good method I can use to put the image back together after cutting it up and making each image a button?

I think I could do this using Reactjs, but I'd rather do it all in python in possible because of other parts of the program.

[image: emotion wheel pic im using]

I can make one image a button, or a bunch of different images into a bunch of buttons, but I haven't yet figured out how to make one image a lot of buttons, or place all of those buttons properly togther without their blank spaces overlapping, so I'd rather it all be one whole image if possible.

[image: quick overlap i've done so far]

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Which buttons do you exactly want? Do you want each part in the first ring to have one button associated with it, or each part in the second or third ring? Do you just want each  part with text in it to be a button?

Comment: The only way I can think as of now on top of my head is creating a canvas. Then when you click on any portion of the canvas you get the X and Y. Based on that, by trigonometry you can calculate the radious and angle. It is then a matter of manually creating a dictionary where angle = the portion of the image you want. Then depending on the radious selecting again that "portion" inside the "portion".